# 'Boundary' options in EMD package of R language

Tags: r

I am applying the Empirical Mode Decomposition method on my time series data using the package 'EMD' of R language. Inside the EMD package, there is a function called `extractimf`. One of the input arguments to this function is `"boundary"`. `"boundary"` can take on 5 values i.e., `"none"`, `“wave"`, `“symmetric"`, `“periodic"` or `“evenodd"`. For the `"evenodd"` method, the reference is mentioned in the documentation. But for `“wave"`, `“symmetric"`, `“periodic"` methods, what are the references? I looked into the other references of documentation but none of them has discussed these three boundary methods. It is preferred if someone can explain in their answer about the pros and cons of using `“wave"`, `“symmetric"`, `“periodic"`, or `“evenodd"` methods as well as mention their references. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can find some info here: https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2009/RJ-2009-002/RJ-2009-002.pdf

Comment: Thank you @AK88. I would be requiring the details of when to use each of them.